# Prove there is a mapping between two partial linear operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, partial-derivative

I am asked the following--

Given real coefficients $a_{jk}, a_l$, define a general 2-variable linear differential operator by

$$L=a_{11}\partial_{xx} + 2a_{12}\partial_{xy} + a_{22}\partial_{yy} + a_{1}\partial_{x} + a_{2}\partial_{y} + a_0$$

Given the operator, define its discriminant by

$$D=a_{12}^2-a_{11}a_{22}$$

If $D=0$, prove that there exists a linear transformation $T:R^2\rightarrow R^2$,

$$(x,y)\mapsto T(x,y)=(\epsilon,\eta)$$

such that the operator becomes

$$L=\partial_{\epsilon\epsilon}+{lower \space order \space terms}$$

I am stuck, I don't know where to start... I know I am supposed to collapse the result into the first term in a matrix, but I'm not really sure how to get there. I think it involves breaking up the operators?

Comment: Hint: Write the quadratic operators as $\partial_x^2,\partial_x \partial_y, \partial_y^2$, then complete the square as you would in high school algebra.

Comment: thanks! i solved it.

Comment: Good! Consider writing up your solution as an answer. That'll allow you to mark the question as answered and provide the opportunity for others to provide constructive comments.

Comment: ok i will do that in the morning

Answer (score 1):

First note that

$$D=a_{12}^2-a_{11}a_{12}=0
\Rightarrow a_{12}=\sqrt{a_{11}a_{22}}$$

whence, expanding through the second-order derivatives,

$$L=a_{11}∂_{x}^2+2\sqrt{a_{11}a_{22}}∂_{x}(∂_{y})
+a_{22}∂_{y}^2+a_{1}∂_{x}+a_{2}∂_{y}+a_{0}$$
$$=(\sqrt{a_{11}}∂_{x}+\sqrt{a_{22}}∂_{y})^2+
a_{1}∂_{x}+a_{2}∂_{y}+a_{0}$$
$$=∂_{\epsilon}^2+
a_{1}∂_{x}+a_{2}∂_{y}+a_{0}=∂_{\epsilon \epsilon}+
a_{1}∂_{x}+a_{2}∂_{y}+a_{0}$$

where we have let $∂_{\epsilon} = \sqrt{a_{11}}∂_{x}+\sqrt{a_{22}}∂_{y}$. Hence the mapping is

$$T(x,y)=∂((\sqrt{a_{11}},\sqrt{a_{22}}),(0,0))$$